# Firebase [Android] Get list from database to map?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A User in my Firebase database can have friends, that are other Users. Here is how it is structured:

```
users
|
|---123
|    |
|    |---username: "Adam Sandler"
|    |
|    |---friendlist
|        |
|        |---456: true
|        |
|        |---789: true
|---456
|    |
|    |---username: "Chris Rock"
|
|---789
:     |
:     |---username: "Kevin James"
```

I want to load the `friendlist` part into a `map` and then load it into a `recyclerview`. This is from my Fragment:

```
FirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference(
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() //Lets say this equals "123"
                );
        mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendList, FriendViewHolder>(
                FriendList.class,
                R.layout.friend_view,
                FriendViewHolder.class,
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("friendlist")
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(FriendViewHolder viewHolder, FriendList model, int position) {
                viewHolder.getTextView.setText(getRef(position).getKey().toString());
            }
        };
```

Here is the other classes:

```
public final class FriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView textView;

    public FriendViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.friendTextView);
    }

    public TextView getTextView() {
        return textView;
    }

}
```

and:

```
public class FriendList {

    private Map<String, Boolean> map;

    public FriendList(){}

    private Map<String, Boolean> getMap(){
        return map;
    }

}
```

When I run the app, the recyclerview is empty. Any suggestion what I might need to do here?

**EDIT:**

I get this warning:

```
W/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError.toException(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:224)
                                                                                           at com.fishindustries.bellyflop.adapter.UserFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onCancelled(UserFirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:44)
                                                                                           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter$1.onCancelled(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:108)
                                                                                           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.notifyCancelledListeners(FirebaseArray.java:124)
                                                                                           at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseArray.onCancelled(FirebaseArray.java:105)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbox.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqv.zzZT(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

In my Firebase database rules, I have set the rules under `/users` to allow read if `auth != null` and write if `$uid == auth.uid`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Can you give an input here, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For load data you must create

```
class User(){
  String username;
  Map <String, Boolean> friendlist;
  ....
}
```

Then get list from User and create list.
But with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter you give a list of users!!

If you want to create list of friends fore one user, you need 
to get query for UserId and get list for adapter.

So, first do not create User class or FriendList class. 
Just add this, must be work:

```
     DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(                                   
               FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                 userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
Map<String, Object> userData = (Map<String,Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue(); 
Map <String, Boolean> resultMap = (Map<String,Boolean>)userData.get("friendlist");
adapter.add( new ArrayList<>(resultMap.keySet()));
            }
                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){
                                            // Logic for failure is here...   
                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: Do you mean Map<String, Boolean> ?? I did that and it still does not work

Comment: Thanks I will look into that and I will get back to you in a moment!

Comment: @Carlton, maby must convert  new ArrayList<>(uniqueRecs.keySet());

Answer (score 3):

`Permission denied` generally means it is from a `rules` issue. Try reading the data via Database simulator first to make sure your `rules` are correctly set up.

And then, as Sergey's answer. I would try `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to retrieve values. And if you need to handle realtime data `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` is useful. But if you don't It's better to make your own custom recycler adapter. In my case, I use custom recycler adapter for non-realtime and realtime database since `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` has some limits.

Comment: Thanks for the help @wonsuc ! I don't know why there was a rules issue, but it stopped right now.